# How can I make a list object to dataframe in long format with tidyverse in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
dd <- list(c("2020-1-2","SDF","fff,33"),
           c("2020-1-3","KKK","ffd,23","fffdf,23","ssfds,43"))
dd
# [[1]]
# [1] "2020-1-2" "SDF"      "fff,33"  

# [[2]]
# [1] "2020-1-3" "KKK"      "ffd,23"   "fffdf,23" "ssfds,43"

ddtarget <- data.frame(date= c("2020-1-2","2020-1-3","2020-1-3","2020-1-3"),
                       category = c("SDF","KKK","KKK","KKK"),
                       element = c("fff,33","ffd,23","fffdf,23","ssfds,43"))
ddtarget
#       date category  element
# 1 2020-1-2      SDF   fff,33
# 2 2020-1-3      KKK   ffd,23
# 3 2020-1-3      KKK fffdf,23
# 4 2020-1-3      KKK ssfds,43
```

I want to transform dd to ddtarget with tidyverse such as map() or similar functions, but I can not make it by myself. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you supposed to differentiate the 1st, 2nd from the 3rd-5th elements of your 2nd input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first two columns are always of length 1, and the 3rd one are all the remaining elements here is a way using `map_df`

```
purrr::map_df(dd,~tibble(date = .x[1], category = .x[2],element = .x[3:length(.x)]))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  date     category element 
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 2020-1-2 SDF      fff,33  
#2 2020-1-3 KKK      ffd,23  
#3 2020-1-3 KKK      fffdf,23
#4 2020-1-3 KKK      ssfds,43
```

Answer (score 2):

If the first element is always the `date`, and the second element is always the `category`, and the remaining elements are always the `element`, you can do the following:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dd, function(x) {
  data.frame(date = x[1L], category = x[2L], element = tail(x, -2L))
}))
#       date category  element
# 1 2020-1-2      SDF   fff,33
# 2 2020-1-3      KKK   ffd,23
# 3 2020-1-3      KKK fffdf,23
# 4 2020-1-3      KKK ssfds,43
```

If `length(dd)` is large, you could consider using `data.table::rbindlist` which is much more optimized than `do.call(rbind)`: `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(...))`

I also suspect there's something wrong earlier in your pipeline -- where did `dd` come from? Why does it take this format?

If you have control of the steps that created `dd`, you might consider designing your pipeline more holistically.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `unnest_wider` with `pivot_longer`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(dat = dd) %>%
   unnest_wider(c(dat), names_repair = ~c('date', 'category', str_c('V', 3:length(.)))) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = V3:V5, values_to = "element", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   select(-name)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  date     category element 
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 2020-1-2 SDF      fff,33  
#2 2020-1-3 KKK      ffd,23  
#3 2020-1-3 KKK      fffdf,23
#4 2020-1-3 KKK      ssfds,43
```